# where to convert .xls file to json file inside Nifi data flow?

Tags: excel, apache-nifi

I am new to NiFi but i want to make a flow in NiFi in which i will take a .xls file from a FTP point and convert it to JSON file and put it in websocket server. But there is no processor regarding Excel. It will we a great help if someone let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

[NIFI-2613](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2613) This feature is in progress

In the meantime,

First, please try to use the option provided [XLS to CSV](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/36875/where-to-convert-xls-file-to-csv-file-inside-nifi.html). Basically use the provided script to convert xls to csv.

Then, follow [Nifi CSV to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928832/convert-a-csv-file-to-json-using-apache-nifi) to achieve your goal

Comment: Thanks for this it is a great help