# How to convert CSV to JSON using Apache Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

How to convert CSV to JSON using Apache Nifi?
I have a CSV file and I need to covert to json. How to draw a normal flow diagram. Please tell me the properties and figure details.
My understanding is 4 block has to there. 1.GenerateFLow 2.ConverttoAvro 3.Converttojson 4.Savethefile. I am new to the Nifi and I have installed nifi, struggling to configure

```
"model","speed","mileage"
"audi",4,2
"benz",4,10
"bmw",7,4
"jaguar",7,22
```

My Json

```
[
  {
    "model": "audi",
    "speed": 4,
    "mileage": 2
  },
  {
    "model": "benz",
    "speed": 4,
    "mileage": 10
  },
  {
    "model": "bmw",
    "speed": 7,
    "mileage": 4
  },
  {
    "model": "jaguar",
    "speed": 7,
    "mileage": 22
  }
]
```

I went through [Convert a CSV file to JSON using Apache NiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928832/convert-a-csv-file-to-json-using-apache-nifi)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The approach that you have described in question is **`old`** `(needs to follow if you are using prior to NiFi-1.2 version)`.

**Starting from [NiFi-1.2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3658)** introduced `record oriented processors`.

- For your case Use **`ConvertRecord`** processor and Configure/enable **Record Reader(CSVReader)/Writer(JsonSetWriter)** controller services.
- Then NiFi **ConvertRecord** processor reads the incoming `CSV` data and writes the output flowfile in `JSON` format.

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/115311/convert-csv-to-json-avro-xml-using-convertrecord-p.html) link describes step-by-step procedure how to `convertCsvtoJson` using ConvertRecord processor.

`Starting from NiFi-1.2 Version` ***Flow:***

```
1.GenerateFlowFile 
2.ConvertRecord
3.SaveFile (Using PutFile/PutHDFS)
```

`Prior to NiFi-1.2 Version` ***Flow:***

```
1.GenerateFlowFile
2.InferAvroSchema
3.ConvertCSVToAvro
4.ConvertAvroToJSON
```

Comment: Just one query how upload the input file. Do we need to do Get FIle before the convert(step2)

Comment: @user1464878, Yes you can use either `GetFile (or) ListFile + FetchFile` processors to fetch input file from Local. https://pierrevillard.com/2017/02/23/listfetch-pattern-and-remote-process-group-in-apache-nifi/

Comment: Perfectly worked. The link provided solved my need. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

You can create a python script that convert a CSV to JSON. Then add an 'ExecuteScript' processor to run this script with your flow. The Python script should be able to read the flow, convert CVS to JSON and then return the JSON into the flow.
You can also use different programming language if you don't like Python.